# How to Convert an Infinite Series with Coefficients $a_i$ to a Series with Coefficients $1/a_i$

Tags: polynomials, power-series, inverse

I am working with an infinite series of the form $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i$, and I am interested in understanding how to transform this series into a new series where each coefficient $a_i$ is replaced by its reciprocal, yielding a series of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_i} x^i$.

Given the initial series representation:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
$$

I would like to know if there is a mathematical operation or transformation that allows for the conversion to:

$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_i} x^i
$$

- Is there a direct method to perform this coefficient transformation within the series?
- What are the implications of such a transformation on the convergence and properties of the original series?
- Are there any known functions or specific examples where this type of transformation is applicable or has been studied?

Any insights, references, or examples related to this question would be greatly appreciated. I am particularly interested in understanding the mathematical foundations and implications of this transformation.

---

To clarify and provide an explicit example as requested, let's consider the two series examples you've given:

- The geometric series representation where the function $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ is expressed as the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^n$. This is based on the power series expansion of the function $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, which converges for $|x| < 1$.
- The logarithmic series representation where the function $-\ln(1-x)$ is expressed as the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} x^n$. This series represents the Taylor series expansion of the natural logarithm function $-\ln(1-x)$, and it also converges for $|x| < 1$.

---

Note: assume $a_i \neq 0$

Comment: So you cannot define this on polynomials, of course. Do you expect this to converge for any nonzero $x$ if the original series converges for some $x$? What formal properties will your formal series have?

Comment: I think that for any real $a,b$ you can find $a_i$ such that $\sum a_ix^n$ has radius of convergence $a$, while $\sum a_i^{-1}x^n$ has radius of convergence $b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It seems that for $ab>1$ your claim is not true.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please give an explicit example of what you want to do. For example, what does "within the series" mean? For the transformation you want to get, what is its domain?

Comment: I added an example and an assumption. I hope it is clearer now.